# Visual Studio 2022: Warning MINVER1001 not a valid Git working directory. Using default version 0.0.0-alpha.0

Tags: visual-studio, minver

How to resolve the following Warning in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022:

```
Warning MINVER1001  '...\Markdig' is not a valid Git working directory. Using default version 0.0.0-alpha.0.    Markdig ...\src\Markdig\MinVer  1   

Warning: Unable to locate repository with working directory that contains directory '...\src\Markdig'.  Markdig ...\microsoft.build.tasks.git\1.1.1\build\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.targets 25
```

Here's a Screensnap shot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Temporarily add this to your .csproj file to see more detailed information. In my case when processing MinVer rules, it showed that I was not the owner of the folder and it saw this as suspicious.

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <MinVerVerbosity>diagnostic</MinVerVerbosity>
</PropertyGroup>
```